# Libreoffice conversion from doc to docx stuck in ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, linux, docx, libreoffice, doc

I am developping a program to extract content from a docx file. However, a lot of my available files are in .doc format and not .docx, so I use libreoffice to convert them.

For one particular doc file, the conversion doesn't work, and I don't know if it's a bug or a misuse on my part.

Here is the code that I use. "entry" is the file name.

```
if entry.lower().endswith('.doc'):
  if sys.platform == "linux" or sys.platform == "linux2":
      print(entry)
      os.system(f"lowriter --convert-to docx '{entry}'")
```

Instead of creating a docx file, this appears in my directory. I have waited for about 10 minutes and the program is stuck here.

[image: Created file]

Does anybody have an idea of chat is going on here, and if I can fix it? I guess I can put a time limit on the conversion and skip the file if it takes too much time but that would mean that I can't utilize the content of this file later.

Comment: Did you try to open this particular file in LO (with GUI) to check that it is readable?

Comment: It does seem that this file cannot be opened like that... In that case, is there a way I can adapt my code to not get stuck indefinitely on this conversion?

Comment: A timeout looks like a good idea. I never worked with the CLI of LO, there might be options to let it return an error code or to watch the timeout by itself, IDK.